# SUSE Auto login execute commands

Tags: linux, command-line, suse

I am pretty new to the world of bash.
I am trying to achieve one thing, that is to have a more easily readable form of a command.

For example:
I usually need to do 
`su - <user>`

What I want to do is type `changeto <user>`, and then when I press enter in the backend the actual command 
`su - <user>` should be executed.

Comment: There seems to be two question here. You can only ask one question per question. You can ask as many as you like. I stripped off the 2nd one. Feel free to ask in another question, but I feel that people may think that you have not done any research. Add what you have tried, and what happened.

Comment: I don't get it: How is `changeto` shorter than `su -`? And what back\end? did you miss out something important?

Comment: well I am going for more like human readable language kind of thing. I can easily catchon if i know how to do one. There are other long commands that I use on daily basis.

Comment: I edited your question (You can also do this), to make it say what you said in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an alias or with a simple shell function.

With an alias:

```
alias changeto='su -'
```

With a shell function:

```
changeto () {
    su - "$@"
}
```

Both of these would behave the same when used on the command line.

You would put either of these (but not both) in whatever place that you usually put alias definitions, most likely into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` if you are using `bash` as your interactive shell.  The alias or shell function will be available in the *next* shell that you start (for example if you open a new terminal).

If using the alias, then the shell would simply replace the word `changeto` with `su -` when you use that command. Any further arguments that you use (a username, for example) will be tagged on to the end of that.

If using the shell function, the shell would call `su -` followed by whatever other arguments you pass to the function.  In this case, the effect would be the same as with the alias.